# string-split in DrScheme

Tags: string, scheme

How do I do equivalent of python's str.split in DrScheme? SRFI-13 doesn't seem to have it provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`regexp-split`](http://docs.plt-scheme.org/reference/regexp.html#%28def._%28%28lib._scheme/base..ss%29._regexp-split%29%29), probably, with `regexp-quote` on the string first to make it not behave like a regexp.

Answer (score 0):

string-tokenize in SRFI-13